# rubyの配列をdllに渡して、dllで処理された配列をrubyで受け取る方法について

Tags: ruby, c, array

C言語で以下のようなdllを作成しました。

```
void example(int *a)
{
　for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
　　a[i] += 1;
　}
}
```

このdllに対し、rubyの配列 `hoge[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` を渡し、処理された配列 `hoge'[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` をruby側で受け取るにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

dllの呼び出しは、

```
Win32API.new(DLL_NAME, 'example', 'p', 'v')
```

を使用しております。

ご解答、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Win32APIは古くなっているようですが、お使いの ruby のバージョンはどれでしょうか？ 新しいものについては本家に記事があるようです[How can I "natively" use a DLL from Ruby - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272971/how-can-i-natively-use-a-dll-from-ruby)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
バージョンは1.9ですが、参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

windows が無いので、mac の情報で恐縮ですが、`ruby 2.2.0` だと下記で出来ました。

```
# test.rb
require "fiddle/import"
module M
  extend Fiddle::Importer
  dlload "libtest.dylib"
  extern "void example(int *a)"
end

hoge = [0] * 10
p hoge
hoge = hoge.pack('i*')
M.example(hoge)
p hoge.unpack('i*')
```

実行結果は下記です。

```
$ ruby test.rb
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

ruby 2.2 からは fiddle を使うそうです。windows でも使えるのではないかと思います。

> library fiddle
>   *.dllや*.soなど、ダイナミックリンクライブラリを扱うためのライブラリです。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/library/fiddle.html

配列をやりとりするには、文字列に変換する必要があるらしいので、pack, unpack を使っています。

> ○○の配列を関数に渡したい
>   これを呼び出したい場合は以下のように Array#pack を使用します。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.0.0/library/fiddle=2fimport.html

Comment: 詳しいご解答ありがとうございます！
諸事情により、Rubyのバージョンは変更できないためfiddleは試しておりませんが、Win32APIでもpack, unpackでやりとりできました！
また機会がありましたらよろしくお願い致します。